# Как парсить array из json

Tags: json, dart

Каким образом я могу распарсить подобный json?

```
[{"id":"2fd7b680-dfe3-430a-e792-08d7dae3fc66","group":"КИ19-11Б","weekType":"odd","dayOfWeek":"wednesday","term":{"classNumber":1,"startsAt":"08:30:00","endsAt":"10:05:00"},"instructorName":"Кириллова Светлана Владимировна","classType":"Practice","audience":{"id":3,"number":"117","corpus":"УЛК","border":null},"subject":{"id":5,"name":"Математический анализ","description":null}},{"id":"af4e8c34-0532-4038-e794-08d7dae3fc66","group":"КИ19-11Б","weekType":"odd","dayOfWeek":"wednesday","term":{"classNumber":2,"startsAt":"10:15:00","endsAt":"11:50:00"},"instructorName":"Кушнаренко А В","classType":"Practice","audience":{"id":6,"number":"410","corpus":"УЛК","border":null},"subject":{"id":3,"name":"Введение в профессиональную деятельность","description":null}}]
```

Comment: А на выходе вы что хотите получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В заголовке один вопрос, в теле вопроса: "как его парсить", ответ на первый вопрос уже дали [тут!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917114/how-to-parse-json-without-key-in-flutter), а второй, если вам нужен массив объектов, принцип такой, Допустим есть JSON вида:

```
    {
      "tags": [
        {
          "name": "dart",
          "quantity": 12
        },
        {
          "name": "flutter",
          "quantity": 25
        },
        {
          "name": "json",
          "quantity": 8
        }
      ]
    }
```

Описываем класс Tag

```
 class Tag {
  String name;
  int quantity;

  Tag(this.name, this.quantity);

  factory Tag.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return Tag(json['name'] as String, json['quantity'] as int);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{ ${this.name}, ${this.quantity} }';
  }
}
```

декодируем строку(наш JSON), и пробегаемся с помощью метода map() по списку тегов

```
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  String arrayObjsText =
      '{"tags": [{"name": "dart", "quantity": 12}, {"name": "flutter", "quantity": 25}, {"name": "json", "quantity": 8}]}';

  var tagObjsJson = jsonDecode(arrayObjsText)['tags'] as List;
  List<Tag> tagObjs = tagObjsJson.map((tagJson) => Tag.fromJson(tagJson)).toList();

  print(tagObjs);
}
```

на выходе имеем, нужный список:

```
[{ dart, 12 }, { flutter, 25 }, { json, 8 }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем как использовать, прочитайте [ответ от @EugeneKuznetsov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1131091/261617)

```
final data = dataFromJson(jsonString);

...

import 'dart:convert';

List<Data> dataFromJson(String str) => List<Data>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Data.fromJson(x)));

String dataToJson(List<Data> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Data {
    final String id;
    final String group;
    final String weekType;
    final String dayOfWeek;
    final Term term;
    final String instructorName;
    final String classType;
    final Audience audience;
    final Subject subject;

    Data({
        this.id,
        this.group,
        this.weekType,
        this.dayOfWeek,
        this.term,
        this.instructorName,
        this.classType,
        this.audience,
        this.subject,
    });

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        id: json["id"],
        group: json["group"],
        weekType: json["weekType"],
        dayOfWeek: json["dayOfWeek"],
        term: Term.fromJson(json["term"]),
        instructorName: json["instructorName"],
        classType: json["classType"],
        audience: Audience.fromJson(json["audience"]),
        subject: Subject.fromJson(json["subject"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "group": group,
        "weekType": weekType,
        "dayOfWeek": dayOfWeek,
        "term": term.toJson(),
        "instructorName": instructorName,
        "classType": classType,
        "audience": audience.toJson(),
        "subject": subject.toJson(),
    };
}

class Audience {
    final int id;
    final String number;
    final String corpus;
    final dynamic border;

    Audience({
        this.id,
        this.number,
        this.corpus,
        this.border,
    });

    factory Audience.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Audience(
        id: json["id"],
        number: json["number"],
        corpus: json["corpus"],
        border: json["border"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "number": number,
        "corpus": corpus,
        "border": border,
    };
}

class Subject {
    final int id;
    final String name;
    final dynamic description;

    Subject({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.description,
    });

    factory Subject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Subject(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        description: json["description"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "description": description,
    };
}

class Term {
    final int classNumber;
    final String startsAt;
    final String endsAt;

    Term({
        this.classNumber,
        this.startsAt,
        this.endsAt,
    });

    factory Term.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Term(
        classNumber: json["classNumber"],
        startsAt: json["startsAt"],
        endsAt: json["endsAt"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "classNumber": classNumber,
        "startsAt": startsAt,
        "endsAt": endsAt,
    };
}
```