# Как импортировать json в объект (Flutter)?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Подскажите как импортировать json в объект во Flutter и использовать повторно в других классах?
Пример: получаю response c ключами 'timezone', 'access_token', 'userId'

```
signIn(String userName, pass) async {

final String serverKey = '##############';
final String url = 'https://example.com';
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
Map data = {
  'server_key': serverKey,
  'username': userName,
  'password': pass
};
var jsonResponse;
var response = await http.post(url, body: data);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  var res = jsonResponse;
  print(res);
  list = res.map<Token>((json) => Token.fromJson(json)).toList();
  if (jsonResponse != null) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['access_token']);
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage()),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    print(jsonResponse['access_token']);
  }
} else {
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
  print(response.body);
}
}
```

Создаю класс с названием Token

```
class Token {
  String timezone;
  String access;

  Token({this.timezone, this.access});
  factory Token.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Token(timezone: json["timezone"], access: json["access_token"]);
  }
}
```

Как теперь использовать переменную access в других dart файлах?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1142227/flutter-api-post/1142313#1142313

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как парсить array из json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1131054/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-array-%d0%b8%d0%b7-json)

Comment: Не импортировать, а сериализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вы хотите сериализовать такой же json в других местах проекта. Вот несколько советов как сделать так, чтобы таких вопросов не возникало. Разбей этот метод на части, сделай отдельный метод который сделает запрос и вернёт тебе сериализованный объект. Далее отдельный метод для перехода на другой экран.

```
List<Token> signIn(String username, String password) async {
   final String serverKey = '##############';
   final String url = 'https://example.com';
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await 
   SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   Map data = {
     'server_key': serverKey,
     'username': username,
     'password': password
   };
   var jsonResponse;
   var response = await http.post(url, body: data);
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
     var res = jsonResponse;
     if (jsonResponse != null) {
      sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['access_token']);
      final List<Token> list = res.map<Token>((json) => Token.fromJson(json)).toList();
     }
   } else {
    return null;
  }
}

Future<void> onSignInTapped() async {
   final List<Token> tokens = await signIn();
   if (tokens != null) {
     setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage()),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
   } else {
    setState(() {
     _isLoading = false;
    });
   }
}
```

В результате чего в любом месте проекта можно будет вызвать метод **signIn**, который, в случае успешной сериализации вернёт нужный вам объект, желательно положить метод **signIn** в какой-то архитектурный слой отвечающий за запросы к API.

Comment: да, это я понял. А как теперь использовать любую переменную из массива без FutureBuilder и ListBuilder? Чтобы использовать значение переменной в любом месте кода импортируя его.